# Cropped/displaced camera view in rviz (gscam)

Tags: rviz, gscam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using gscam to stream the view from a USB camera. However, when viewing it in an rviz camera display only a cropped view is shown. It seems like the view is displaced by half the view size to the right and down, so only a quarter of the view is shown. When using image_view everything looks fine. Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

According to mplayer the camera image's resolution is 640x480.

I'm using the default camera_parameters.txt:

> ```
> # Camera intrinsics
> [image]
> width
> 640
> height
> 480
> [default]
> camera matrix
> 1.00000 0.00000 1.00000
> 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000
> 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000
> distortion
> 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
> rectification
> 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000
> 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000
> 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000
> projection
> 1.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000
> 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.00000
> 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000
> ```

and this is my GSCAM_CONFIG:

> ```
> v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! identity name=ros ! fakesink"
> ```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10948/cropped/displaced-camera-view-in-rviz-(gscam)/) by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 317 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The available version of gscam doesn't properly publish TF frame information, and so it won't work with an rviz camera display. See [this branch](http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/gscam/) for this functionality.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zihan Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/14141/zihan-chen/) on 2014-03-31**:
Jon, you are everywhere.